# A statistical test to determine if the change over the years is statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, test-for-trend

*Somehow my brain resists to understand statictics, sadly.*

I have been searching a proper statistical test to analyse my data.
I would like to test if the trend I see in my data is statistically significant or not. You can see the data I have below. The percentage means, I calculate the rate of deforestation by year based on total deforestation occured within 19 years (loss in 2001/total loss). I though it will be meaningfull in this way to compare the numbers.

[image]

Is there any way to say, *there is a significant increase or decrease over the years*? I am thinking of Mann-kendal, Chi-square and linear regression(to analyse the slope?) I couldnt decide which of them would be proper. Please I am open to any suggestion!!

[image]

Comment: Can you post a simple plot of the two variables?

Comment: @user2974951 Do you mean a kind of line chart? I edited the question. Please let me know if you mean something different.

Comment: Yes, this will suffice. It gives a clear picture of the behavior.

Comment: My question is to @RogerJ
Please let me know How to run the bivariate test with only one variable.
Thank you

Comment: repeat measures anova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image you provided it looks like there may be a linear relationship with time. In which case this can be tested with a simple Pearson correlation coefficient, which measures the overall strength of linear relationships.

You could also estimate a slope with a linear model, which would tell you by how much does your variable of interest increase for each incremental year and if this increase is statistically significant, if that is of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions! How can I apply a linear model? Is that a linear regression? and Can I directly use Excel functions or "add trend line"?

Comment: @youcodegirl Unfortunately I am not that familiar with Excel so I cannot help you there, but I am pretty sure that you can estimate a corr. coef. or a linear (regression) model in Excel as well, but I do not know if it has a test for these coefficients or how they are implemented, which is what you are asking. I assume that a "trend line" is the slope from a linear model, now you just need a test for it.

Comment: I see, Thank you a lot!! Now I have a path to follow!

Comment: @user2974951, wouldn't "pearson r" require two continuous variables to get the corr. coeff.? how to go about translating/transforming the time/years into a continuous variable to be able to feed to "pearson r"?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala Well, if the time variable is year, like OP's table shows (I don't remember) then you can just use that as a numerical variable. Otherwise if it's datetime you can convert it into integers as well (unix time or some such).

Answer (score 1):

This data is nonlinear. Using the bivariate test (Maronna and Yohai 1978) it shows a shift in 2012 of 2.3 at p<0.01. There is a trend in the first period, but not in the second. I would conclude there was a change in clearing methods at that time.